# From standard HMM to Bayesian HMM

Tags: bayesian, hidden-markov-model

I'm trying to understand what the difference between a standard HMM and a Bayesian HMM is. Wikipedia just briefly mentions how the model looks like but I need a more detailed tutorial. Does someone know of a paper or an implementation which I can look at?

Also I have issues with the terminology used. What does it practically mean if you "place/put a Dirichlet prior on a distribution"?

Comment: Are you at all familiar with prior distributions and posterior distributions? If not, read through an example of doing [Bayesian inference on binomial data (i.e., given an observed sequence of coin flips, infer the probability of heads)](http://goo.gl/Mdl9D), then it's a straight forward generalization to multinomial data (i.e., given some rolls of a biased $K$-sided die, infer the probability of observing each side). The latter problem, which involves "placing a Dirichlet prior" on the probability vector, is the same inference one does with a Bayesian HMM.

Comment: Here's a [good, short paper on Bayesian HMMs for part-of-speech tagging](http://cocosci.berkeley.edu/tom/papers/bhmm.pdf) which has a great explanation of why the Bayesian approach is useful.

Comment: So can anyone give an example how it would look like?

In the sense of a 6-sided die, the uniform probability vector would be {1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6} right? And would would it mean if I place a Dirichlet Prior on that?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the Dirichlet prior, I believe it's saying that you have a set of $n$ variables which are all percentages/proportions between 0 and 1 and all add up to 1. (That is $x_1 \dots x_n$ where $0 \le x_i \le 1$ and $\sum x_i = 1$.) In the case of HMM's, that could be used to model the probability of transitioning to one of $n$ possible states, or the probability of emitting one of $n$ possible symbols.

The [Dirichlet wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) says it pretty well, especially the section entitled "Conjugate to categorical/multinomial".